# Appending an image with an alternate source in case the first one isn't available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dom

I have an two images `img_A.jpg` and `img_B.jpg`.

I need to append `img_A.jpg` inside a `div` in the `body`, however, in case that image is not accessible or is not available, I want `img_B.jpg` to be used instead.

***Something like:***

```
$('div').append('<img src="img_A.jpg" />' || '<img src="img_B.jpg" />');
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: i posted live demo,Chenge name of image For image1.src in code,You will get NOImage,else  okImage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may do this :

```
$('div').append(
     $('<img>').attr('src',"img_A.jpg").on('error',function(){
          this.src = "img_B.jpg"
     })
);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/pimod/1/edit)

---

If your goal is to set the favicon of a site, you may do this :

```
$('head').append(
     $('<link rel="icon">').attr('href',"img_A.jpg").on('error',function(){
          this.href = "img_B.jpg"
     })
);
```

Comment: @dystroy error function take care of file not available ?

Comment: Still How would you do it with `$('head').append(<link rel="shortcut icon" href="sh_imgs/favicon_A.jpg" />` OR `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="sh_imgs/favicon_B.jpg" />)` in the same manner?

Comment: @SivaRajini Am Not getting any Error, are you sure?

Comment: @SivaRajini Yes, you get an error event when the file isn't available